# Writing a C# application to accept a password

Tags: c#, passwords

The C# [Process.Start method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overload that allows passing a SecureString to use as a password. Is it possible to write a program that accepts that SecureString and saves it as a variable? If not, how is that overload used?

Comment: That specifies the local/domain user to launch the process as.

Comment: Did you actually read the page you posted? I think this clears everything: ``Use this overload to create a new process and its primary thread by specifying its file name, user name, password, and domain. The new process then runs the specified executable file in the security context of the specified credentials (user, domain, and password). ``

Comment: Damn. I suspected that was the case, I was hoping I was wrong.